# Mschart - Bar Chart Not Updating in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

In my project values are updating in every 1 second; Based on the values I am plotting Bar chart. What is happening is it is not updating and plotting real time values.
For Example 
If Value is `(30,10)` it plots. 
If value is `(30,45)` it updates and plots.
If value is `(30,5)` Chart not updates and not get plots.

Please Help what to do
I have tried `Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();`
but this is not working as my values are updating in every 1 second.

Comment: It seems you need to set a minimum and maximum for chart `Axis-Y` or if you prefer, perform a `ResetAutoValues`.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - Also you should show relevant potions of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to set a minimum and maximum for your chart `Axis-Y` or if you prefer, make the axis automatically reset its minimum and maximum.

If you set a specific minimum and maximum value for Axis-Y, then the chart Axis-Y will not change it's values automatically and when you add new point to chart, the Axis-Y values will not update and only the points will update:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 200;
```

Also you can set the chart to automatically change range for Aixs-Y, this way the Axis-Y updates it's minimum and maximum and your chart Axiy-Y changes:

```
chart1.ResetAutoValues();
//Or this
//chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale()
```

**As an example:**

Put a `Chart` and a `Timer` on a form. Set the interval of Timer to 1000 ms, and set it's `Enabled` to `true`. Handle `Load`  event of form and `Tick` event of timer and write these codes:

```
private void From1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add("Serie1");
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 200;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int y = new Random().Next(0, 200);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(30, y);
}
```

Comment: I Have setted minimum and maximum range of my Y axis.

Comment: Check the answer for example :)

Comment: @ParthDesai Did you check the example? :)

Comment: Great! Thank you for your feedback :)